# Creating a web-table with bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a web-table which should be able to run on desktop, smartphone and tablet.

Therefore I use HTML, CSS, PHP and the Bootstrap-package.

Besides I use the option that less 800 pixel the table change to a column: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table.

There are 2 problems where I don’t know how to solve them:

1: The left column (Bundesland) causes problems. Look in the attachment please (image 1 and 2). The column in the first image is ok. In image 2 the data have to display in every box.

2. I don’t know how to resize the box, that the gap between the left and right panel border is closed.

Do you have ideas?

Thank you very much!

Best regards.

Konrad

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any attachments? :)

Comment: Can we see your html?  Is this a simple typo in the td tags @ Bundesland & Ort?

Comment: Now you can see the attachments! :)

Comment: This is the PHP-Snippet for column "Bundesland" in image 1: echo "<tr><td data-title='Bundesland' class=".$class.">";if($var_bl==false) echo $lrp[$key]['BL'].":";echo "</td>  <td data-title='Ort' class=".$class.">".$lrp[$key]['Stadt']."</td>";

Answer (score 0):

To remove the paddings at the left and right side of the columns use the class 'row'. So for example:

```css
.foo,
.bar {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.foo .col-md-12,
.bar .col-md-12 {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="foo">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      Without row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        With row
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#nesting

Comment: Thank your very much @Hewlett, it works for the window less 800 Pixel. Now it does not work for the desktop window andymore. The body-element is bigger as the heading-element. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @UBA_KP, can you please show a screenshot? Beside that, you can also add additional styling that targets the paddings on desktop.

Comment: It's not possible to add a screenshot here. Do you have an idea how to do this in the field "Add Comment"?

Comment: You can just update your post, or you can post the link to the screenshots.

Comment: Add this to the style of your table: table-layout:fixed;

Comment: I tried this. But it does not work. Look in the attachement again please. Thank you! :)

Comment: Maybe the lablet-layout is at the wrong position? Maybe there's an alternative?

Comment: I've done this, but it does not work. Maybe the syntax or the positions are wrong setted? I've added the code-snippet again. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Now it works with

```
table {border-collapse: separate;}
```

I also used the snippet

```
<div class="row">
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to install a 3rd party library for your requirement

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/integration/responsive-bootstrap.html